# Matplotlib installed but not found mac python 2.7

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation, pip

I currently have Python 2.7 installed on my machine. I have worked with matplotlib successfully in the past, but recently I re-ran an old file and it could no longer find the module:

> "ImportError: No module named matplotlib"

When I run `pip install maplotlib`, it says I already have it in my Libraries folder:

> "Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python"

On other pages, people seem to have Python in their /usr/local/...folders, so I'm not sure if that is the issue.

I was asked to run these commands and got the following:

which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

which pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip

echo $PYTHONPATH

python --version
Python 2.7.12

I'm guessing that since echo is returning nothing that is an issue.

Comment: `/usr/local` is typically for people that install another version of Python using Homebrew (https://brew.sh/), so you don't need to worry about that. Have you tried `python -m pip install matplotlib`, just in case `pip` is being executed in the wrong place?

Comment: A bit of diagnostic will help. Can you add to your question the output of the following commands? `which python`, `which pip`, `echo $PYTHONPATH`, `python --version`. Also, do you now how matplotlib was installed in the first place?

Comment: echo returned nothing I'm guessing that is the issue. I updated the post with all of the commands.